# long型の値を渡したい

Tags: java

`nouNum` を読んでいるメソッドがlong型の値を引数としており、returnでlong型を返したいです。

long型を返すには `out` を `char[]` ではなく、違う型にするのでしょうか？

```
class nouNum {
    public  String Num01(String in){
        char[] out = in.toCharArray();
        int[] mul = { 2, 5, 9, 9, 5, 7, 2, 5, 7 };
        int n = Math.min(out.length, 9);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            out[i] = (char)((out[i] - '0') * mul[i] % 10 + '0');
        return new String(out);
    }
}

private String check(long in){
    DecimalFormat form01 = new DecimalFormat();
    String t = exFormat1.format(in);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> long型を返すには `out` を `char[]` ではなく、違う型にするのでしょうか？

いいえ。
`out`変数が`char[]`型であることは `out[i] = (char)((out[i] - '0') * mul[i] % 10 + '0');` を成立させるための必須要件です。
`return new String(out);` で`String`型を返している箇所を書き換えて`long`型にしましょう。

`String`型を`long`型に変換する方法としては、[`Long#parseLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-)を使うのが一般的です。
ご質問のコードでは[戻り値の型](https://nobuo-create.net/java-beginner-13/#i-3)が`String`型になっていますので、こちらを`long`型に書き直すことも忘れずにご対応ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！